# Moving a database with pg_dump and psql -U postgres db_name < ... results in "ERROR: relation "table_name" does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jdbc

I moved my PostgresQL database from one hard drive to another using

```
pg_dump -U postgres db_name > db_name.dump
```

and then

```
psql -U postgres db_name < db_name.dump
```

I created the database db_name the same way in both instances.  In the new database when I run my Java program with a JPA query (or a JDBC query) I get this error:

```
"ERROR: relation "table1" does not exist"
```

The query is:

```
select count(0) from table1
```

I know I've got a connection because if I change the password in the connection parameters I get an error.

For some reason in the new PostgresQL instance it thinks that table1 does not exist in the imported schema.

If I change the query to

select count(0) from myschema.table1

Then it complains about permissions:

```
"ERROR: permission denied for schema myschema"
```

Why would the permissions be different?

The table table1 exists in myschema because I can see it in the pgAdmin tool.  All the rows were imported into the new PostgresQL instance.

When I do a query from Java the combination of pg_dump and psql created a problem.

What do I need to do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Are you moving to the same version of PostgreSQL? There might be issues if you make a dump with pg_dump 8.3 and try to restore it in Postgresql 8.4. Anyway, assuming that it is the same version try the following:

Dump all global objects, such as users and groups (don't know if they were missing in your dump):

```
pg_dumpall -g -U postgres > globals.sql
```

Dump schema of database:

```
pg_dump -Fp -s -v -f db-schema.sql -U postgres dbname
```

Dump contents of database:

```
pg_dump -Fc -v -f full.dump -U postgres dbname
```

Now restore.

```
psql -f globals.sql
psql -f db-schema.sql dbname
pg_restore -a -d dbname -Fc full.dump
```

That is my $0.02. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am moving from 8.3 to 8.4.  I'll change my backup scripts to use your more comprehensive approach.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: I would add verbose flag(-v) to pg_restore for large database. 
`pg_restore -a -v -d dbname -Fc full.dump`

Comment: What's the point of dumping the schema twice (in plaintext and compressed) if you're going to `pg_restore -a` anyway? Why not `pg_dump -Fc -a -v -f data.dump`, for example? Or skip the schema step altogether, and just do globals in one step and everything else in the other?

Comment: In the restore block, on the second line, I assume that filename should be 'db-schema.sql'?

Comment: Best answer so far, was facing many issues to restore my database with incomplete answers.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered this problem. Then I realized that I forgot to install `postgis` extension.

Don't forget to install the extensions you use.

Comment: Many thanks man. It was the issue i struggled with for hours. Didn't even know about postgis existance, i'm new to postgre world. Just installed postgis from repo and all worked.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it by changing the database privileges to public CONNECT and the schema privileges for public and postgres = USAGE and CREATE.

My backup scripts apparently didn't preserve the privileges, at least not when moving from 8.3 to 8.4.