# What does `-Fp` mean for pg_dump option?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When i look up [Moving a database with pg_dump and psql -U postgres db_name < ... results in "ERROR: relation "table_name" does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518218/moving-a-database-with-pg-dump-and-psql-u-postgres-db-name-results-in-er) and found `-Fp` option from @John P 's answer

I have look up for documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html
but i cannot find any desciption about `-Fp`

So what does `-Fp` mean for ?  Any Description ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means `--format=plain`:

> -F format
>   --format=format
>
> ```
> Selects the format of the output. format can be one of the following:
>
> p
> plain
>
>     Output a plain-text SQL script file (the default).
> ```